# SwiftUI strangely shifting location of certain Views when invoking contextMenu modifier

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, contextmenu, frame

I'm having an issue where some SwiftUI views (under certain configurations) are shifting their location to the center of the screen when I use the .contextMenu(menuItems:) modifier, and I can't figure out why. I've recreated the problem in a simplified manner in the following code samples:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Text("hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

[GIF that demonstrates how the triangle shifts to center screen for some reason due to the context menu invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHmjD.gif)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
        .position(x: 0, y: 0)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .bottom)
        .contextMenu {
            Text("hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

[GIF that demonstrates how the circle shifts to center screen and somehow gains a sharp edge due to the context menu invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rULbB.gif)

I would really appreciate it if anyone knows what's going on here. I'm on Xcode 12.5.1, macOS 11.4, and iOS 14.5.

Comment: It's probably the `position` - try removing that

Comment: @aheze removing ```position``` does work but unfortunately I can't do that to solve the problem that this is abstracting... any chance you know why ```position``` is causing problems? Do you think it's worth submitting a [technical support incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) to Apple in case this is a SwiftUI bug?

Answer (score 0):

By adding certain frame to shape you can fix the issue but I don't have any explanation.

```
       Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            .contextMenu {
                Text("hello world")
        }
```

Comment: Interesting... adding the frame changes the location of the triangle, which unfortunately won't work for me. Do you think this could be a bug in SwiftUI? Is it worth submitting a [technical support incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) to Apple? @aheze